# Where have I introduced extra monadic structure in my implementation of the EitherT catamorphism?

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to write the solution to Haskell Programming from First Principles - 26.3 - Ex 5.

The problem is to write a version of the either catamorphism which works on the monad transformer variant, EitherT. The type of the function should be:

```
eitherT :: Monad m => (e -> m c) -> (a -> m c) -> EitherT e m a -> m c
```

For reference, here is the EitherT newtype as defined in the book:

```
newtype EitherT e m a = --why does the book use e a for the type parameters instead of a b? Error type?
  EitherT {runEitherT :: m (Either e a)}
```

In addition, I have a working `instance Monad m => Monad (EitherT e m)`,  as well as Functor and Applicative before it.

The type signature given in the problem statement suggests that I will need to use the Monadic functionality of m, or possibly of (EitherT e m). However, I wrote a version that only uses fmap which I thought would work:

```
eitherT :: Monad m => (e -> m c) -> (a -> m c) -> EitherT e m a -> m c
eitherT fe fa = fmap (either fe fa) . runEitherT
```

This does not compile. Specifically, the compiler is complaining that I have constructed the infinite type c ~ mc (full output below). I will take this as yet another clue that the problem is meant to be solved with some monadic function. However, I would like to understand where my approach is adding in that structure. So far, I can't.

Here is my reasoning for the code I wrote:

1. `runEitherT :: EitherT e m a -> m (Eihter e a)`
2. `either fe fa :: Either e a -> c`
3. `fmap (either fe fa) :: m (Either e a) -> m c`
4. `fmap (either fe fa) . runEitherT :: EitherT e m a -> m c`

This seems to match exactly what the type should be for `eitherT fe fa`.

Can someone point out where I have gone wrong?

The full error message:

```
 Haskell> :l EitherT.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling EitherT          ( EitherT.hs, interpreted )

EitherT.hs:36:17: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: c ~ m c
      Expected type: EitherT e m a -> m c
        Actual type: EitherT e m a -> m (m c)
    * In the expression: fmap (either fe fa) . runEitherT
      In an equation for `eitherT':
          eitherT fe fa = fmap (either fe fa) . runEitherT
    * Relevant bindings include
        fa :: a -> m c (bound at EitherT.hs:36:12)
        fe :: e -> m c (bound at EitherT.hs:36:9)
        eitherT :: (e -> m c) -> (a -> m c) -> EitherT e m a -> m c
          (bound at EitherT.hs:36:1)
   |
36 | eitherT fe fa = fmap (either fe fa) . runEitherT
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured out the answer while I was reviewing my question's formatting. In case it helps anyone else, here it is:

My solution works if the types of `fe` and `fa` were of the form `(a -> c)` rather than `(a -> m c)`.

Changing the type signature of eitherT to reflect that lets the code compile. The specific flaw in my reasoning is in step 2, which should have read:

2. `either fe fa :: Either e a -> m c`

Comment: To implement with your original signature, see the (important) combinator `join :: m (m a) -> m a`